# How to parse html via javascript inside a Filemaker webviewer using tinyMCE

Tags: javascript, filemaker

I have a webviewer inside a Filemaker 14 DB with the folowing code for the webviewer.

```html
"data:text/html,<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"http://example.com/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js\"></script>
    <script type=\"text/javascript\">
        tinymce.init({
            selector: \"#mytextarea\",
skin: \"lightgraynofonts\",
height: 500,
browser_spellcheck : true,
fontsize_formats: \"8pt 10pt 12pt 14pt 18pt 24pt 36pt 48pt\",
font_formats: \"Andale Mono=andale mono,times;\"+
        \"Arial=arial,helvetica,sans-serif;\"+
        \"Arial Black=arial black,avant garde;\"+
        \"Book Antiqua=book antiqua,palatino;\"+
        \"Comic Sans MS=comic sans ms,sans-serif;\"+
        \"Courier New=courier new,courier;\"+
        \"Georgia=georgia,palatino;\"+
        \"Helvetica=helvetica;\"+
        \"Impact=impact,chicago;\"+
        \"Symbol=symbol;\"+
        \"Tahoma=tahoma,arial,helvetica,sans-serif;\"+
        \"Terminal=terminal,monaco;\"+
        \"Times New Roman=times new roman,times;\"+
        \"Trebuchet MS=trebuchet ms,geneva;\"+
        \"Verdana=verdana,geneva;\"+
        \"Webdings=webdings;\"+
        \"Wingdings=wingdings,zapf dingbats\",
 plugins: \"table textcolor hr preview\", 
    tools: \"inserttable\",
    toolbar: \"forecolor backcolor bold italic underline alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify formatselect fontselect fontsizeselect cut copy paste bullist numlist outdent indent table preview superscript undo redo removeformat\"

        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form onsubmit=\"return submitForm()\">
<button type=\"submit\">Save</button>
        <textarea id=\"mytextarea\">"& Product Templates Interface::Description & "</textarea>

    </form>
</body>
<script>
function submitForm() {
var theParam = escape(tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent());
var theURL = \"fmp://$/" & Get ( FileName ) & "\?script=tiny&param=\" + theParam;
window.location = theURL ;
document.getElementById(\"mytextarea\").value = theParam;
return false;
}
    function show(){
        var data = document.getElementById(\"mytextarea\").value;
        alert(tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent());
    } </script>
</html>"
```

there is a script called tiny with just pulls the param and sets the same field as above.

Now the problem seams to be if any of the code with in the tinyMCE textarea uses a span or div it will therefore have a set of " (quote marks). Now this is where FM errors and results in nothing shown. so I need to somehow escape the " (quote marks)  first but have not been able find a solution that filemaker allows.
a string.replace() inside a javascript function wouldn't work as the single escaped quote mark (\")stopped filemaker closing the windows.
any ideas or pointer?

Comment: I loaded your code in web viewer and I do not see any errors. Are you talking about editor not displaying? This does not show with nothing in text area either

Comment: managed to get this running after removing the plugins references. I will play with this more to recreate the problem, but did you try to replace double quote characters with a single quotes?

Comment: the problem I have is getting the script to read the params once the save button is clicked. try only adding Bold, which is <strong>Text</strong>  this will work. but if a different formatting feature is chosen that needs to use a <span> or a <div> then a class is added eg. <span style="color:red">text</span> <- this is the problem because of the " marks

Comment: sorry just to clarify the above code needs you to download the tinymce.min.js and upload it to make it work. I tried using a CDN version of the tinymce.min.js but it would not load on the windows machine. So i have it loaded on a local linux apache that works fine. but just play about to find a working solution. sorry I can't be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

A method I recently learned about at FM DevCon 2015 (but have yet to try) involves exporting your HTML content to the temporary directory and using a `file://` URL to load it from there, instead of using the Data URI method.

That approach might also help you debug a problem like this, because you can load the exported page in Chrome or Firefox and use more sophisticated debugging tools.

Comment: sounds promising. let me know if you can get it to work, ill try now and report what I find.

Comment: I found a way to work but it uses the PHP API to get the POST values and push them into that record. It works. but I was hoping for a more filemaker only method

Comment: @StuSays: How big a chunk of data are you pushing? If it's less than ~2,000 characters, you can use an `fmp://` URL to call a script in FileMaker Pro on the client machine. 

If it's longer than that, it will still work on OS X or iOS, but not in Windows. (WinOS has a hard-coded 2,048 char limit on URLs).

Comment: It will be biggish eg. a ecommerce product description more than 2048char. So I think the way I now have it where the webviewer pushes the data to a php pages which then inserts it into the filemaker database via the PHP API and then redirects it back to a third php page ready to do that loop again. this works well. I found even escaping the URI text would not work. it feels like filemaker is doing some processing before letting the param available to a script. and hence dropping support for " marks inside a param, even if its encoded. feels like a bug but cant be 100%sure.